# Rule of Thumb for number of observations required to train a model with n independent variables?

Tags: predictive-modeling, feature-selection, machine-learning-model, feature-engineering, overfitting

I am aware adding more features to a model leads to overfitting of a model. Is there a rule of thumb for minimum number of rows required to build a model with n features in order to build a generalized model?